# Configure nginx with multiple locations with different root folders on subdomain

Tags: nginx, webserver

I'm looking to serve the root url of a subdomain and directory of a subdomain to two different folders on my server. Here is the simple set-up that I have and is not working...

```
server {

    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name test.example.com;

    location / {
            root /web/test.example.com/www;
    }

    location /static {
            root /web/test.example.com/static;
    }
}
```

In this example going to `test.example.com/` would bring the index file in `/web/test.example.com/www`

and going to `test.example.com/static` would bring the index file in `/web/test.example.com/static`

Answer (score 313):

You need to use the `alias` directive for `location /static`:

```
server {

  index index.html;
  server_name test.example.com;

  root /web/test.example.com/www;

  location /static/ {
    alias /web/test.example.com/static/;
  }

}
```

The [nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias) explains the difference between root and alias better than I can:

> Note that it may look similar to the root directive at first sight, but the document root doesn't change, just the file system path used for the request. The location part of the request is dropped in the request Nginx issues.

Note that `root` and `alias` handle trailing slashes differently.

Comment: He doesn't need `alias`. Please, read [the official docs](http://nginx.org/r/alias), not the community wiki filled by users. Quote: *When location matches the last part of the directive's value it is better to use the root directive*.

Comment: This worked for me except that it's missing a trailing slash. The alias should read:
alias /web/test.example.com/static/;

Comment: @VBart the docs do say exactly what you quote them as saying, but they don't justify that instruction at all - it seems like an arbitrary style choice. Do you see any logical reason behind it?

Comment: This was working without tailling / in my case. But the best way to do this seems like https://stackoverflow.com/a/30038528/2716796

Comment: Do I need to use "try_files $uri $uri/ =404;" under "alias" line ?

Comment: Just need to remember... as i just found out ...   alias = "REPLACE"  root = "APPEND"

Comment: I would really like to know why the instructions say to use `root` rather than `alias` under those circumstances. It isn't explained, and it doesn't work on my configuration, but `alias` works.

Comment: @blissweb could you pleas clarify your comment?   Are you pointing out a functional distinction between alias and root?

Comment: @elysch yes, if you had /static and root /root/  the path would be  /root/static/    if you had /static and an alias /root/   the path would be /root/ only.  The initial path would be completely replaced.

Answer (score 139):

The Location directive system is

Like you want to forward all request which start **`/static`** and your data present in **`/var/www/static`**

So a simple method is separated last folder from full path , that means

Full path : `/var/www/static`

Last Path : `/static`   and First path : `/var/www`

```
location <lastPath> {
    root <FirstPath>;
}
```

So lets see what you did mistake and what is your solutions

Your Mistake :

```
location /static {
    root /web/test.example.com/static;
}
```

Your Solutions :

```
location /static {
    root /web/test.example.com;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a rather SEVERE limitation on Freedom To Do What I Want. I want URIs starting with a certain path to be served from a directory that doesn't contain that URI path in its physical file path. With this solution, I am FORCED to put my documents on disk under a path that ends with "/static". I don't like this at all. I want absolute and complete freedom of putting the files wherever I want.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski then use the "alias" directive

Answer (score 61):

```
server {

    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name test.example.com;

    location / {
        root /web/test.example.com/www;
    }

    location /static {
        root /web/test.example.com;
    }
}
```

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

Comment: what's the different with asked?

Comment: @Wooden the difference: `root /web/test.example.com;` instead of `root /web/test.example.com/static;`. nginx maps the path specified by *location* to the diretory tree and since the path and the source directory share the same name, it works with `root`.

Comment: This format is discouraged. Better to have a parent `root` under `server`. See [Nginx config pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/?highlight=alias#root-inside-location-block).

Answer (score 13):

A little more elaborate example.

Setup: You have a website at `example.com` and you have a web app at `example.com/webapp`

```sh
...
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  root   /usr/share/nginx/html/website_dir;
  index  index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

  location /webapp/ {
    alias  /usr/share/nginx/html/webapp_dir/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /webapp/index.html;
  }
}
...
```

I've named `webapp_dir` and `website_dir` on purpose. If you have matching names and folders you can use the `root` directive.

This setup works and is tested with Docker.

NB!!! Be careful with the slashes. Put them exactly as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this, I will suggest you set up this command too.

```
location /static/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host/static; // if you change the directory and the browser can't find your path
    alias /web/test.example.com/static/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check two different directories for the same URI use this config:

```
server {
...
    root /var/www/my-site/public/;
...
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
...
    location / {
        root /var/www/old-site/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
...
}
```

If Nginx couldn't find file in `/var/www/old-site/dist/` directory, then it will try file in `/var/www/my-site/public/` directory, but as we said to Nginx to try files with `$uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args` patterns, so Nginx will try `/index.php$is_args$args` in `/var/www/my-site/public/` directory. not `$uri`

If you want to complete your fallthrough, then replace `/index.php$is_args$args` with `/fallthrough$uri` and then add the `location /fallthrough { ... }`  with the alias key to your target directory.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block