# CakePHP2 coexising with CakePHP3 on same domain

Tags: cakephp, nginx, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

Let's suppose an application written in Cake2. This application is huge. This application is mainly about CRUD's. Rewriting this application into Cake3 could be very time-consuming.

Now, I need o extend this application with lots of functionality. More and more CRUD's.

Application interface must look same, there must be single authorization and authentication provided by old app, or maybe rewritten into new app.

Now, is there any way, that existing application ( in Cake2 ) could work on same domain with Cake3?

I know that added functionality could work on subdomain like

- Cake2 app is domain.tld
- Cake3 app is storage.domain.tld

but how complicated, problematic could be set things as

- **domain.tld/[beefs|chips|sausages]** <- Cake2
- **domain.tld/storage <- Cake3**

Opinions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy. Just configure your webserver to route /storage to your Cake3 app and all other to the Cake2 app.

- [Configure nginx with multiple locations with different root folders on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570321/configure-nginx-with-multiple-locations-with-different-root-folders-on-subdomain) (concept is the same)
- https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/
- Google knows a lot more :)

Comment: wondering, can it share the session? AFAIK, token for form will be mismatch, right?How to pass data to single view using 2 different apps