# How do I change the root folder that a node module will look for?

Tags: node.js, express, express-vhost

I have a nodejs app. Inside this app, I have a secondapp and I use vhost to use one or other. The problem is: my second app uses a node module that needs a config file (file.json). This module look for this file in the root folder. However, the module is looking at the root folder of the project (the root app), and I want that the module look at the root folder of the SecondApp.

So, the "somenodemodule" is using the "file1.json". But I want to use the "file2.json". How can I change the root folder that the "somenodemodule" will look for?

This is the code of the root app:

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require('path');
var connect = require('connect')
var vhost = require('vhost')

var secondapp = require('./secondapp/app');

app.use(vhost('secondapp.com', secondapp));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Homepage First App');
});

var porta = process.env.PORT || 3000;

http.listen(porta, function(req) {
    console.log("servidor rodando");
})
```

This is the code of the secondApp:

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var somenodemodule = require('somenodemodule');
var path = require('path');

var secondapp = somenodemodule();

app.use(secondapp);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Homepage Second App');
});

module.exports = app;
```

And this if my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

Comment: is the config file coming from something your installed with npm or is it a file you created?

Comment: the module I installed has the config file ('node_modules/mymodule/config.json'). However, it is possible to override this config file. To do this, I need to create a custom config.json in the app root folder. So, the config file is a file I created

Comment: do you have 'somenodemodule' installed in both node_modules directories?

Comment: no, just in the "SecondApp/node_modules" directory

Comment: are you overriding the config file by passing it to some module like somemodule("path/to/config.json") or are you just providing a file in a directory with a specific name ?

Comment: the some module looks for a config file in the root directory. I am just providing a config file in the root directory

Comment: can you move the file2.json from the second app directory to the root directory?

Comment: if not one hakcy thing you could do is open up the code in somenodemodule and see where the module is consuming the config file and change the path there

Comment: yes, I can. But this is not the right solution for my case... I want to have a third app, and this third app will have a "file3.json"... so, for every app, I will have a different config file...

Comment: I could change the path inside the somenodemodule file. But I'd like to found a solution that does not change the module code. I want my app working with after "npm install".

Comment: nested node_modules is tricky business. Not sure you can config vhost to choose the root dir.. you might try and use NGINX instead of Vhost

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6960

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570321/configure-nginx-with-multiple-locations-with-different-root-folders-on-subdomain

Comment: this app will be deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I was trying to avoid changing nginx config. But it seems that this is the only way...

Comment: Might be one but not one i know of, good luck though :)