# NGINX - FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream

Tags: nginx

I got this error message when trying to set WordPress as a subdirectory. `File not found.` when view the URL `example.com/blog`

```
2020/05/05 20:55:56 [error] 906#906: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"
```

example.conf

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location /blog {
        alias /var/www/blog;
        index   index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this config instead

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.vm www.example.vm;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        root /var/www/laravel/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location /blog {
        root /var/www/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }



    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Final updated answer tested and works. The issue here is the location path setting of alias/root directory. Maybe you can refer to this for more info in future.
[Configure nginx with multiple locations with different root folders on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570321/configure-nginx-with-multiple-locations-with-different-root-folders-on-subdomain)

Comment: still same. is it because of the permission issues?

Comment: have you try to restart nginx & php-fpm ?

Answer (score 1):

This:

It has been suggested in a number of other "solutions" to this error that it has something to do with SCRIPT_FILENAME setting. I observed (eventually) that the parameter is set in a file, /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf however in my config file, /etc/nginx/sites-available/x10.local.conf it has this directive: include fastcgi_params; Now there are both fastcgi_params and fastcgi_param files in the /etc/nginx/ directory. They appear to be identical except that the fastcgi_params file does not include the SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter. I added the line to the fastcgi_params, restarted php-fpm and nginx and found it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

It has been suggested in a number of other "solutions" to this error that it has something to do with SCRIPT_FILENAME setting.  I observed (eventually) that the parameter is set in a file, /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf however in my config file, /etc/nginx/sites-available/x10.local.conf it has this directive:
include fastcgi_params;
Now there are both fastcgi_params and fastcgi_param files in the /etc/nginx/ directory.  They appear to be identical except that the fastcgi_params file does not include the SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter.  I added the line to the fastcgi_params, restarted php-fpm and nginx and found it finally worked.