# nginx path based routing

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I would like to to route requests based on a path to two different Angular applications. So when i request http://example.com/admin is routes to one app http://example.com/client routes to the second app. I have the following config but all requests are always sent to the nginx default page. Configuration is as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        location /admin {
                root /home/ubuntu/apps/admin/;
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
        }

        location /client {
                root /home/ubuntu/apps/client;
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
        }
}
```

No other confs are in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and nginx.conf is default post install on Ubuntu. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are your files located? `/home/ubuntu/apps/admin/index.html` and `/home/ubuntu/apps/client/index.html`?

Comment: Have you tried `alias` instead of `root` ? Also, you don't need `$uri/` with a trailing slash. Perhaps you don't need routing at all - simply set the `root` outside of any `location` block and then use a single `location /` block with just `try_files`

Comment: @RichardSmith correct. two separate angular apps deployed to those folders.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I did that and it helped partially. I am not sure why taking off `$args` is the only thing that worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You were using the wrong value for [the `root` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root). In both locations the correct value for the `root` directive is `/home/ubuntu/apps`, which means you can simplify the configuration by using just one `root` directive by moving it into the `server` block.

Of course you can use the `alias` directive - but as [the manual states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)   :

> When location matches the last part of the directive’s value ... it is better to use the root directive instead.

The other problem is that your `try_files` statements are pointing to the wrong `index.html` file.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/ubuntu/apps;

    location /admin {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html;
    }

    location /client {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /client/index.html;
    }
}
```

Note that `server_name _;` is not necessary - see the [Server Names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) document.

Also, `index index.html;` is not necessary being the default value for [the `index` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index).

Comment: Thank you! This does simplify things. Removing `$args` is still required and that is what was killing me.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you cannot use multiple `root` directives but instead need to use `alias` ([Configure nginx with multiple locations with different root folders on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570321/configure-nginx-with-multiple-locations-with-different-root-folders-on-subdomain)). With that, I would still get 404s until I took off `$args` from the `index.html`. After that everything worked fine (don't ask how long it took to figure that out). Working config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;
        index index.html;

        location /admin {
                alias /home/ubuntu/apps/admin;
                try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }

        location /client {
                alias /home/ubuntu/apps/client;
                try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }
}
```